# Verification of a fact, separable Banach spaces, closed subset.

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces

I am reading a proof and it says to verify the following: 
Suppose $Z$ is a separable Banach space and $F$ is a closed subset of $Z$. Let $\mathcal{O}$ be a countable basis of open subsets of $Z$. We have 
$x,y\in F \implies x+y\in F$ iff for all $O,O'\in\mathcal{O}$ with $O\cap F\neq \emptyset$ and $O'\cap F\neq \emptyset$, we have $(O+O')\cap F \neq \emptyset$.

It is clear that => holds. I am having trouble with the other direction.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $x,y\in F$, but $x+y\notin F$. $F$ is closed, so $x+y$ has an open nbhd $U$ such that $U\cap F=\varnothing$. Addition is a continuous function from $Z\times Z$ to $Z$, so there are $O,O'\in\mathcal{O}$ such that $x\in O$, $y\in O'$, and $O+O'\subseteq U\subseteq Z\setminus F$.

Comment: Concise and to the point. Thank you.

Comment: @Dom: You’re welcome.